# Japanese Kanji handwriting input

Tags: android, ime, handwriting

I'd just like to ask if there are plans to provide a built-in handwriting IME for Japanese Kanji.  And perhaps for Traditional and Simplified Chinese as well.

The reason I ask is because is the only thing thing that I seem to miss from the iPhone.  It's really convenient to be able to naturally input the said characters on the phone and I've still yet to find a good enough input method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The add-on IME [MultiLing Keyboard](https://market.android.com/search?q=multling%20gingerbread%20hanwriting) provides a Chinese/Japanese handwriting input plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I tried [MultiLing Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.klye.ime.latin&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5rbHllLmltZS5sYXRpbiJd) with the [Plugin Japanese 日本語](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=klye.plugin.ja) AND [Plugin HanWriting](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=klye.hanwriting) (You need all three to make it work). This does the job, for a free app. However, I find it too complicated and lacking functionality. Also, the hand recognition is not too forgiving.

Yesterday I found this app that does what you want. **This one is AMAZING.** It is simple and it really works great: [7notes with mazec (Japanese)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sevenknowledge.sevennotesproduct&feature=search_result) They do have a [free 10-day trial version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sevenknowledge.sevennotestrial&feature=more_from_developer) available.

Answer (score 0):

I've not found anything as good as the iOS Chinese IME, but I have had some success with the program [Kanji Yomi Lite](https://market.android.com/details?id=jp.ne.biglobe.inda3.kanjiyomilite) - this allows you to read kanji from photos (which didn't work for me), or draw on a blank canvas and OCR it (which works fairly well).

Comment: Thanks Gavin. But I was actually pertaining to Android. :)  I use the Chinese IME for iOS as well. :)

Comment: Oops - should have checked the tags.. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am the author.

Not sure how current this is, but ctegaki has just recently been released. There can still bugs, but in general it's quite stable. See https://github.com/asdfjkl/ctegaki-lib

Ctegaki can recognize not only kanji, but also hiragana and katakana. Moreover compared to other engines, it can recognize characters even when written with a wrong stroke order or stroke number...

Since it's written in C I wonder how difficult it is to port to iOS. Personally, I do not own an iPhone and am not familiar with iOS development however...